# when adding servlet api in eclipse, tomcat failing to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

First I got a error

> "The import javax.servlet.annotation cannot be resolved"

..So I have added servlet-api.jar file into my libraries. After adding this jar file, I am getting

> "**Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**"

error when starting the server.

When I remove the servlet-api.jar file, tomcat server is starting perfectly and I am getting

> servlet.annotation error

again.

Please help me in resolving this error. I have seen into some similar posts but did not find it useful.

Comment: Tomcat provides a `servlet-api` library specific for its version in `tomcat/lib`so your project does not have to provide it. Add tomcat to your project as `targeted runtime` in project preferences of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed servlet-api library and added tomcat as targeted runtimes. Now am not getting servlet.annotation error but i can't start tomcat.

Comment: could you post tomcat start trace error?